# What is causing these blocks to appear an Excel 365 print out?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

We print out orders sometimes on an excel spreadsheet like the example below and once printed, white blocks appear randomly across the headers or customers information.

What causes this?

[excel order print out example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtA5l.jpg)

Comment: You should edit the image of the Excel page and mark the places where the white blocks are appearing. This is will make it easier for people to see what exactly you are describing.

Comment: it is quite clear to see.. the blocks appear over address 1 and 2, the product title next to the SKU header, above the postcode, phone number and email to the right...

Comment: Did the blocks appear randomly or fixed? How about coping to Word and print the same table?

Comment: @Lee I haven't tried copying the table to microsoft word and printing that way, I will test it. Also, the blocks appear random. Some of the data has been copied across from Google Sheets, but even on a brand new document, typing all the headers etc in from scratch they still appear. It's not an issue with our printheads or low ink as every other document prints fine, it is just excel.